# how to traverse a unicode tamil word character by charcter in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, tamil

I want to know how many characters are there in a Unicode string (Tamil) and then  check the character1 and character2 for particular occurrences.
I am able to split the word into characters, but I do not know how to traverse through them character by character using the word length.

> Example : word : "எஃகு".
>   It should return no of characters as 3, and I should be able to print word[0] as 'எ', word[1] as 'ஃ' and word[2] as 'கு'.

I want to check like:

```
    if word[0] is a vowel:
        if word[1] is "ஃ":
           then print word[0]+word[1]+word[3] (as எஃகு)
        else:
           print word[0]
```

I want to traverse using no of characters, if no.of.char is 3, then i=0 should help me process 'எ'. 
I saw many questions related to Unicode character processing and length processing. But they all either return byte length or give varying results. So am confused.

Code that I use for splitting them character-wise:

```
    for line in f.readlines():
       letters = utf8.get_letters(line)
       for letter in letters:
          ff.write(unicode(letter))
          ff.write(' ')
```

Sample Input File:

> அன்று
>   அதாவது
>   அஃதான்று

Sample Output File:

> அ ன் று
>   அ தா வ து
>   அ ஃ தா ன் று

Comment: Is your string a `unicode` object or a `str` object?  Can you give an example of some code you have that creates/manipulates such a string?

Comment: Sounds like an ad for http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: It's worth noting that `"எஃகு"` has four Unicode codepoints in it, not three. You can split them out into a list with `list("எஃகு")` (if you're using Python 3) and you'll get `['எ', 'ஃ', 'க', 'ு']`

Comment: @BrenBarn I have given the sample input file.

Comment: @Blckknght : am using a Open-Tamil-Master package for Tamil, it helps me split the word into "எ ஃ கு". It does not split the modifier separately like how you have said.

Comment: @Blckknght: if I use len(u'எஃகு') it gives 4, but visual characters are 3. My point is to process them character wise, which will mean the no of characters will be 3.

Comment: @BrenBarn : I have given the code which I use for splitting the characters

Comment: @Blckknght : I use python 2.7.

Comment: I know nothing of Tamil, but... wouldn't `l = tamil.utf8.get_letters(str)` return a list of letters? that you could address using `l[0]`, `l[1]`, `l[2]`? Number of characters being `len(l)`?

Comment: @Amadan : Yes. l[0],l[1] will address the separate characters, but how do I get a count of how many characters are there. I need a way to get the count of the no of visual characters.

Comment: Does `len(l)` not work?

Comment: @Amadan: if I try to get len(l) , consider the word "எஃகு ", it should return 3(எ ஃ கு - 3 char) or should return 4 ('எ' 'ஃ' 'க' 'ு') . it returns something like this when i put it in a loop: 1
1
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: You're trying to do `len(c)` where `c` is an element of `l` (i.e. number of bytes in a letter, and not number of letters in a letter list). Why are you putting it in a loop in the first place?

Comment: @Amadan : It returns 4 for the above example. But i need the visual character count, which should be 3 and not 4. I hope u get my point. (looping was just a try...)

Comment: No, it does not return 4. I guess I'll have to submit an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package

```
pip install Open-Tamil
```

Code

```
from tamil import utf8
string = u"எஃகு"
letters = utf8.get_letters(string)
print(len(letters))
# 3. Not 4. 
print(letters)
# [u'\u0b8e', u'\u0b83', u'\u0b95\u0bc1']
for letter in letters:
    print(letter)
# எ
# ஃ
# கு
```

Comment: This is good example code. The only change I'd suggest is to use a different name than `str` for the source string, to avoid shadowing the builtin bytestring class name.

Comment: @Blckknght: Good point. I'm not a Pythonista, the `str`-as-type totally didn't even enter my mind.

Comment: the difference between your code and my code is that am reading from a file and hence am not able to prefix the string with "u". I think that is why it returns 4 for me. How do i read from a file and yet prefix with "u". Your code does return 3. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That's another topic entirely, having nothing to do with Tamil, but with encodings and the difference between `str` and `unicode` types. Please read [this article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html). Short answer - use `line.decode('utf-8')` instead of `line`.

Comment: Ignore that - you already have a `unicode` string, because otherwise `utf.get_letters` wouldn't work at all. So something else is the problem at your end. Besides, if the for loop gives you 3 results, there is no way that `len()` would give you 4.

Comment: @Amadan: which version of python are you using? I still cant figure out on why it still returns 4.

Comment: Python 2.7.5. It might help if you show a minimal example, starting from `import`, going through loading a line from the file, ending with printing the letter list length. This way, I can only guess what exactly you're doing (e.g. we can't see how your `f` is opened).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54709/discussion-between-charvi-and-amadan).

Comment: @Amadan can u tell me how to do the character by character splitting without using the utf8.get_letters() function. I wish to do the same splitting for telugu now.

Comment: You should take a look at Open-Tamil source code, `tamil/utf8.py`, and implement a similar code for Telugu, if you can't find a library that already does it. There is nothing in core Python to do it.